# List of abstract class containing extended classes

Tags: java

So my problem is this. I am using java and I am trying to do something like this (I am working offline so it is harder for me to give code examples but if needed I will) :

```
Class A - abstract class
Class B - abstract class with list<A> as property
Class C - extends class A
Class D - extends class B
```

and in this class, in the constructor I am trying to create the list which is in the B properties with a new object from class C.

```
The error is:  Type mismatch: cannot convert from C to A.
```

I can't seem to make it work. Any ideas why?

Edit:

```
abstract public class A {
   public int theInt;
}

abstract public class B {
   public List<A> theList;
}

abstract public class C extends A {
}

abstract public class D extends B {
   public D(){
       this.theList = new ArrayList<C>();
   }
}
```

This is the code and I have a compiliation error like I mentioned.

Comment: It's hard to guess the cause of the error without seeing the code.

Comment: _is harder for me to give code examples but if needed I will_ Yes, we need it. We can't know what is the problem, and where it is without the code you are using

Comment: Add the code you're using and the full stack trace.

Comment: Can you show us the code in the constructor which throws this error? And point out which line throws it?

Comment: Where do you work that you are at work offline ?

Answer (score 2):

Initialize it as

```
List<A> list= new ArrayList<A>();
```

That way you would be able to add any subtype of A

---

If you want to assign `ArrayList<C>` to as it appears from the comment

Do it this way

```
list.AddAll(arrayListC);
```

Comment: Tried it but when I do this I cannt add object to the list i can only create it.

Comment: @user3467713 "Cannot" as in "does not compile" or in "throws an exception" ?

Comment: @user3467713 you would be able to assign not add(except A)..Use `super` instead of extend

Comment: Tried with super still the same error at compilation. Cannot convert from ArrayList<C> to ArrayList<? super A>.

Comment: @user3467713 how are you declaring it,assigning it and adding it..?

Comment: Declaring it like you did exactly, assigning it like this: this.theList = new ArrayList<C>()

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList<C>` does not extend `List<A>`. Therefore the assignment

```
this.theList = new ArrayList<C>();
```

is invalid.

You can fix this by adding a type parameter to `B`

```
abstract public class B<T extends A> {
   public List<T> theList
}

abstract public class D extends B<C> {
   public D(){
       this.theList = new ArrayList<C>();
   }
}
```

You could even add a type parameter to `D`:

```
abstract public class D<T extends A> extends B<T> {
   public D(){
       this.theList = new ArrayList<T>();
   }
}
```

---

#### Alternative:

Just use `ArrayList<A>` instead of `ArrayList<C>`.

---

Please note that `lst.add(x);` will not compile for the following type combinations:

```
    type of lst             |     type of x
============================|================================
  List<? extends A>         |  A
----------------------------|--------------------------------
  List<C>                   |  E extends A but not C
----------------------------|--------------------------------
  List<? extends A>         |  E extends A
```

Comment: But then if i want more objects to extend A and also be able to add them to the list? Like E extend A.

Comment: @user3467713: Edited the answer. Note, that if you want to add objects of types `C` and `E` same `List` and `E` does not extend `C`, then your only option is to use `ArrayList<A>` (since that is the most precise common supertype of `C` and `E`).